# Need to make rest assured API post call with Java for this curl cmd

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, form-data

curl cmd as below :

```
curl -X 'POST' `\
`'``https://api.shared-tst.tanonprod.aegon.io/platform-api-gateway/plan-application/restservices/uploadMultipleDocs``' `\
`-H 'accept: `*`/`*`' `\
`-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' `\
`-F 'files=@Site issue.docx;type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' `\
`-F 'docs=[{"fileName":"Site issue","docTypeCode":"1321"}]' `\
`-F 'accountNumber=683082   00001' `\
`-F 'userId=akatiyar'`
```

```
    response= RestAssured.given().contentType("multipart/form-data").multiPart(
   "file",new File("data\\UploadFile\\Site issue.docx")).
   param("docs","[{\"fileName\":\"Site issue\",\"docTypeCode\":\"1321\"}]").
   param("accountNumber",accountNumber).param("userId", userId).log().all().
   when(). post(endpoint).then().log().all().extract().response();   
response = RestAssured.given().contentType("multipart/form-data").multiPart("retest",
      "data\\UploadFile\\Site issue.docx").formParam("accountNumber",
       accountNumber).formParam("userId", userId). formParam("files",
       "@Site issue.docx;type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-
                officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)formParam"
   ).formParam("docs","[{\"fileName\":\"Site issue\",\"docTypeCode\":\"1321\"}]").
   log().all().when(). post(endpoint).then().log().all().extract().response();
```

Comment: Can you specify which type of error you get with java rest-assured code?